# Stripe: getting "You cannot request any capability other than `transfers`" when only requesting transfers

Tags: payment-processing, stripe-payments

I'm setting up a test connect account through Stripe, but for some reason during the onboarding I get:

> You cannot request any capability other than `transfers` for accounts that are under the `recipient` service agreement.

even though I set the capabilities only to `transfers.requested: true`.

#### Full details:

#### 1. I created a connect account

**Request:**

**POST** `https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts`
**x-www-form-urlencoded body:**

tos_acceptance[service_agreement]: recipient 
capabilities[transfers][requested]: true 
country: AT 
type: express

**Response:**

```json
{
    "id": "acct_1IEKs6Q5kVIyiDKZ",
    "object": "account",
    "business_profile": {
        "mcc": null,
        "name": null,
        "product_description": null,
        "support_address": null,
        "support_email": null,
        "support_phone": null,
        "support_url": null,
        "url": null
    },
    "business_type": null,
    "capabilities": {
        "transfers": "inactive"
    },
    "charges_enabled": false,
    "country": "AT",
    "created": 1611780255,
    "default_currency": "eur",
    "details_submitted": false,
    "email": null,
    "external_accounts": {
        "object": "list",
        "data": [],
        "has_more": false,
        "total_count": 0,
        "url": "/v1/accounts/acct_1IEKs6Q5kVIyiDKZ/external_accounts"
    },
    "login_links": {
        "object": "list",
        "total_count": 0,
        "has_more": false,
        "url": "/v1/accounts/acct_1IEKs6Q5kVIyiDKZ/login_links",
        "data": []
    },
    "metadata": {},
    "payouts_enabled": false,
    "requirements": {
        "current_deadline": null,
        "currently_due": [
            "business_type",
            "external_account",
            "tos_acceptance.date",
            "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "disabled_reason": "requirements.past_due",
        "errors": [],
        "eventually_due": [
            "business_type",
            "external_account",
            "tos_acceptance.date",
            "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "past_due": [
            "business_type",
            "external_account",
            "tos_acceptance.date",
            "tos_acceptance.ip"
        ],
        "pending_verification": []
    },
    "settings": {
        "bacs_debit_payments": {},
        "branding": {
            "icon": null,
            "logo": null,
            "primary_color": null,
            "secondary_color": null
        },
        "card_payments": {
            "decline_on": {
                "avs_failure": false,
                "cvc_failure": false
            },
            "statement_descriptor_prefix": null
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "display_name": "Some business LLC",
            "timezone": "Etc/UTC"
        },
        "payments": {
            "statement_descriptor": null,
            "statement_descriptor_kana": null,
            "statement_descriptor_kanji": null
        },
        "payouts": {
            "debit_negative_balances": false,
            "schedule": {
                "delay_days": 7,
                "interval": "daily"
            },
            "statement_descriptor": null
        },
        "sepa_debit_payments": {}
    },
    "tos_acceptance": {
        "date": null,
        "ip": null,
        "service_agreement": "recipient",
        "user_agent": null
    },
    "type": "express"
}
```

#### 2. Got the onboarding link:

**Request:**

**POST** `https://api.stripe.com/v1/accounts`
**x-www-form-urlencoded body:**

account: acct_1IEKs6Q5kVIyiDKZ 
refresh_url: https://example.com/reauth 
return_url: https://example.com/return 
type: account_onboarding

Response:

```json
{
    "object": "account_link",
    "created": 1611780861,
    "expires_at": 1611781161,
    "url": "https://connect.stripe.com/express/onboarding/<some string>"
}
```

#### 3. Went to the onboarding link

I got an error after pressing **Next** on the **Tell us about your business** section.

> You cannot request any capability other than `transfers` for accounts that are under the `recipient` service agreement. For more information on recipient service agreements, see https://stripe.com/docs/connect/service-agreement-types#recipient.

[image]

Why does stripe think I'm requesting capabilities other than transfers?

Comment: This seems like the error is inaccurate or there's a bug. I'd suggest [contacting Stripe directly](https://support.stripe.com/email) so that the support team can confirm what's going on behind the scenes, but from what I can tell, the Account is only requesting `transfers`.

Comment: I contacted them so we'll see. I just tried to do the same with some old node.js code that use to work to set up connected accounts and it's giving me the same error. So you might be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripe got back to me:

> The error is a bit cryptic but it is likely due to the way you configured Connect Onboarding in your settings in the Dashboard. This error happens because we try to request the `card_payments` capability for this account but it's not supported because you use the recipient agreement type. The reason we ask for that capability comes from the fact that you configured Connect to require that capability for European accounts. You can change this default behaviour in your dashboard settings in Test mode here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/test/settings/applications/express (and you would do the same for Live mode). With your flow you want only Transfers as a capability.

The suggestion worked:

Incorrect Settings:
[image]

Correct Settings:
[image]

It's strange because I used to be able to create accounts from these requests. So the settings must have changed at some point. But to my knowledge I never went and changed them.